# Pick/Sort Algorithm (Knapsack)

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, knapsack-problem

I have encountered an issue with a task I am facing. I have a database with items that all have a "price"-value. They are connected to different "rounds" and the "rounds" have a "tot-value" where these items "price"-value all put together define the "tot-value". So, I want to choose which items to give away and which to save. 5% to 10% of the "tot-value" is supposed to be saved and the rest given away.

I could just select all the items in that round, sort by "price"-value, lowest to highest and then:

```
if ($totSave < $totVal*0.1) { addToSaveArray($item); $totSave += $item['price']; }
```

But I also have a list that is supposed to prioritize the items, set up like this:

```
$prioList[] = array("name" => $list[$i], "price" => $price);
```

So, what is the best approach to this? Do I loop through the $prioList, check if any name matches and then add the price to $totSave or what do you think?

Help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: `select sum(value) from table group by name` ?

Comment: Can't really do this since I have a list to prioritize from. But I narrowed it down to the "knapsack problem". I'll see how it goes from here :)

Comment: "narrowed" to an np-complete problem. have fun with that!

Comment: I think you are trying to solve your problem in the hard way. Depending on your database it can be done with just one query.

Comment: The thing is, it is exactly like the knapsack problem. And I have now come up with a perfect solution! Thanks for taking your time answering my question! :)

Comment: @Fredrik: If you found a solution on your own that can be described in a paragraph or two, or a brief code sample, please consider adding it below as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim asked me to post the answer so that's what I'm doing :) Since this is a knapsack-problem, I googled and found this:
https://github.com/acmeism/RosettaCodeData/tree/master/Task/Knapsack-problem-0-1/PHP

I needed the indexes as well so I went with the top (buggy) one. (Can't post link due to low rep...)

Since that one was buggy, I added a "try"-function. Here it is: 
http://pastebin.com/AycE4Kzm